# Swipe to delete not working most of the time, it removes data from View but not from SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, swipe

I'm a beginner developer. I have a SQLite database in my app. I have successfully added the add, delete and update functions to it. I am trying to implement swipe to delete now, however, I am facing the current problem: Sometimes after I swipe and delete the item, it gets deleted successfully (from the database), sometimes it doesn't, sometimes it deletes the above item, sometimes the item above it by 2 id's. I have done lots of trial and error but I was unable to confirm why this happens.
What always happens is that the item gets deleted from the view, as in it doesn't have its own card anymore (I'm using cardview with recyclerview).

Here's the relevant code (Please let me know if I have not posted any important code, I tried to simplify this) :

MainActivity.java (This is where the recyclerview shows the cards)

```
RecyclerView rv;
MyAdapter adapter;
ArrayList < Player > players = new ArrayList < > ();
int posToDelete;
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

//SWIPE TO DELETE
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback =
    new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
        ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView,
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            players.remove(position);
            posToDelete = (position);

            delete(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

//recycler
rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);


rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
rv.hasFixedSize();

ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new
ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);

//DELETE METHOD
public void delete(int id) {
    db.openDB();
    long result = db.Delete(id + 1);

    if (result > 0) {
        //Deleted toast appears but it doesn't get removed from database?
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    db.close();
}
```

DBAdapter.java

```
Context c;
SQLiteDatabase db;
DBHelper helper;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.c=ctx;
    helper=new DBHelper(c);
}

//OPEN DB
public DBAdapter openDB()
{
    try
    {
        db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return this;
}

//CLOSE DB
public void close()
{
    try
    {
        helper.close();
    }catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//DELETE FROM DATABASE <---------
public long Delete(int id)
{
    try
    {
        return db.delete(Constants.TB_NAME,Constants.ROW_ID+" =?",new 
String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    }catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

As a side question, while debugging to find the problem, I noticed that after successfully deleting an object from the database (using the delete function that works all the time, not swipe to delete), the database just leaves that id spot empty. So for example, if I have objects 1,2,3,4,5 and 6, when I delete 5 and create new objects A and B, it seems the database stores them as 1,2,3,4,(nothing here),6,A,B.

Is this a problem? will it have any bad consequences? or is this completely normal?

Thank you.

****EDIT**** You guys are right, The position passed to the `delete()` method isn't the ID of the object, thanks for pointing that out.

I tried to use `ViewHolder.getItemId()` method but it returns a `long`. I tried both casting it to `integer` and changing the whole method parameters to accept `long` instead of `integer` but the id value I always got was `-1`, this didn't fix anything.

Elsewhere in the app, I get the Id of the item using `onClickListener` because it sends an `intent` to another activity. I was thinking perhaps I could get the Id some other way without any user interaction? because I can't really wait for the `onClickListener` to fire when the user is swiping to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the above comment, I've figured out the mistake was here:
 @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

```
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        players.remove(position);
        posToDelete = (position);

        delete(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I fixed this by creating a new variable and storing the id of that position in the variable, then passing the new variable to the delete method, like this:

```
                        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                        int checkingId;
                        checkingId = players.get(position).getId();
                        players.remove(position);
                        delete(checkingId);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the id that's getting passed to your DBAdapter?

It looks like you're deleting the item from the database based on the adapter position, could it be that these IDs of the items in the database don't match the adapter position?

I've done this swipe-to-delete feature before and I'm pretty sure I used the item id, e.g from your ArrayList of Players and deleted the item based on that from the DB.